# Как конвертировать дом элемент в строку

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Как конвертировать дом элемент в строку, или может еще какую магию посоветуете что бы можно было этот самый элемент целиком хранить localStorage.

Comment: дак и возьмите его `outerHtml` не?

Comment: спасибо) видимо нужно мне js подучить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)**

---

> The `outerHTML` attribute of the element DOM interface gets the
>   serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its
>   descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed
>   from the given string.

что в переводе гласит:
*Атрибут `outerHTML` интерфейса элемента DOM получает сериализованный HTML-фрагмент, описывающий сам элемент и его потомков. Он также может быть использован, чтобы заменить элемент и его дочерние узлы полученной из входной строки.*

зы: свойство поддерживается настолько давно, что даже можно сказать, что большинство пользователей данного ресурса, пожалуй, не видели и не помнят столько древних версий Internet Exploerer.